# Seemingly pointless eval on local variables in a function

Tags: bash, function, eval

I've got some legacy bash code left from a former employee to rewrite (and add documentation while I'm at it). I don't get what is the point of the last two `eval` lines, considering those variables are local.

```
function gen_data_dir {
    local NAME="$1"
    local DB_DIR_VAR="$2"
    local TECH_DIR_VAR="$3"

    local CFG="$DB_CONFIGS_DIR/$NAME"
    if [[ ! -f "$CFG" ]]; then
        echo "no config: $CFG" > /dev/stderr
        return 127
    fi
    echo "processing config: $CFG" > /dev/stderr

    local DB_DIR_="$ANNO_DB_DIR/${NAME}"
    mkdir -p "$DB_DIR_" || return 127

    pushd "$DB_DIR_"
    LC_ALL=C date > DATES
    touch _SHIT

    local TECH_="$DB_DIR_/tech"
    mkdir -p "$TECH_"
    cat "$CFG" > "$TECH_/orig.cfg"
    ${GENOME_DIR}/annotation/parse_db_configs.py "$CFG" "$TECH_"

    rm _SHIT
    popd

    eval "$DB_DIR_VAR"="$DB_DIR_"
    eval "$TECH_DIR_VAR"="$TECH_"
}
```

Am I missing something? And am I right to assume that taking `DB_DIR_VAR` and `TECH_DIR_VAR` is pointless to begin with, since their initial values are never used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not setting `DB_DIR_VAR` and `TECH_DIR_VAR` - it's setting the variables whose names are set in those two variables. So if `DB_DIR_VAR` is equal to `THE_DB_DIR`, it will set `THE_DB_DIR` to the value of `DB_DIR_`.